# custom icons when sharing from personal site to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have seen icons of youtube,skype,blackberry,sony erricsson and all below the shared contents in facebook below shared content,like shown here:

[image]

any idea how I can bring up that kind of icon (ie my custom icon) in facebook when sharing contents from my site?please direct me to some links if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Upload your icon in the [app dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) settings for your app and the posts from your app will have the icon attached